# Top and bottom page borders

Tags: border

I would like to add some borders to my document similar to the image attached -
one is at the top of the page and the other is around the page number. Can I have some recommendations please?

I attach code containing features similar to what I'm working with. I would like the borders to remain in the same position on each page.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption, makecell}
\usepackage{pdflscape,afterpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
Themes and styles also help keep your document coordinated. When you click Design and choose a new Theme, the pictures, charts, and SmartArt graphics change to match your new theme. When you apply styles, your headings change to match the new theme.

\section{Test}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Example_figure}
\caption{Test}
\end{figure}

Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\begin{landscape}% Landscape page
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Table test - contents of table exceeds page width}
\centering
  \small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l*{3}{>{\arraybackslash}X}}
\toprule\midrule[0.5pt]
 & \thead{Column 1} & \thead{Column 2} & \thead{Column 3} \\
\midrule
Item 1 & item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1 & item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1,item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1 & item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1 \\
\addlinespace
Item 1 & item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1 & item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1,item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1 & item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1 \\
\addlinespace
Item 1 & item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1 & item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1,item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1 & item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1 \\
\addlinespace
Item 1 & item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1 & item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1,item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1 & item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1 \\
\bottomrule
 \end{tabularx}%
    \hspace*{-12mm}%
\label{table:comparison of techniques}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example borders]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `fancyhdr` package can help you with the top line. It can also help you at bottom, where you can use something more than just `\thepage` for you page number. Probably place `\smash{\rule[]{}{}}\thepage` there, where you specify the rule dimensions and position.

Answer (score 1):

Here is  an easy way with `titleps`, which comes with `titlesec`, but can be used independently:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption, makecell}
\usepackage{pdflscape,afterpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\usepackage{titleps}

\newpagestyle{mystyle}{%
\widenhead[\marginparwidth][0pt]{0pt}{\marginparwidth}
\headrule
\sethead[~\color{blue}\thesection\enspace\sectiontitle][][]{}{}{\color{blue}\thesection\enspace\sectiontitle~}
\setfoot[{\makebox[\marginparwidth][r]{\thepage~}\smash{\rule[-20ex]{0.6pt}{22ex}}}][][]{}{}{\smash{\rule[-20ex]{0.6pt}{22ex}}\makebox[\marginparwidth][l]{~\thepage}
}
}%
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\section{A First Test}
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
Themes and styles also help keep your document coordinated. When you click Design and choose a new Theme, the pictures, charts, and SmartArt graphics change to match your new theme. When you apply styles, your headings change to match the new theme.

\section{Another Test}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Example-image}
\caption{Test}
\end{figure}

Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.

\begin{landscape}% Landscape page
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Table test - contents of table exceeds page width}
\centering
  \small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l*{3}{>{\arraybackslash}X}}
\toprule\midrule[0.5pt]
 & \thead{Column 1} & \thead{Column 2} & \thead{Column 3} \\
\midrule
Item 1 & item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1 & item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1,item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1 & item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1 \\
\addlinespace
Item 1 & item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1 & item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1,item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1 & item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1 \\
\addlinespace
Item 1 & item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1 & item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1,item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1 & item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1 \\
\addlinespace
Item 1 & item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1 & item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1,item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1 & item 1, item 1, item 1, item 1 \\
\bottomrule
 \end{tabularx}%
    \hspace*{-12mm}%
\label{table:comparison of techniques}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, you could simply use the template which was used to create the image you show in your question.

The template can be found at https://bedienhaptik.de/latex-template/

For more information also see [Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends/184885#184885)